# Global variable's constructor has not been invoked while modify program’s entrypoint

Tags: c++, g++, ld, elf

I want to change the program's entrypoint from main to self-defined function, but it seems that the global variable's constructor cannot be invoked in this case.

code like this:

```
    #include <stdin.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    const char my_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

    class A {
      public:
        A() {
          printf("construct A\n");
        }
    };

    A a;

    int main() {
      printf("main start\n");
    }

    extern "C" {
    int smain() {
      printf("smain start\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    }
```

The compile command like this:

```
g++ -g -Wl,-e,smain -o smain smain.cc
```

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0. You're telling the linker not to enter `start` but to enter your program in `smain`.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with `-e` option gives a replacement for `_start` routine, not `main`.
When you use an alternative for `start`, you will lose initializations which would be a part of the `_start` routine.

In this particular case, you lose the constructor call for `A` because `a` is global. 
You cannot use command-line arguments as well.